# How to set max speed for private interface?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Provision VMs with private network only flag, but I can't specify the max network speed for it.

```
       userName := "xxx"
        apiKey := "xxx"
        endpoint := "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3" 

        sess := session.New(userName, apiKey, endpoint)
        guestService := services.GetVirtualGuestService(sess)

        vGuestTemplate := datatypes.Virtual_Guest{
            Hostname:                     sl.String("testhost1000m"),
            Domain:                       sl.String("domain.com"),
            MaxMemory:                    sl.Int(2),
            StartCpus:                    sl.Int(1),        
            Datacenter:                   &datatypes.Location{Name: sl.String("wdc01")},
            OperatingSystemReferenceCode: sl.String("UBUNTU_LATEST"),
            LocalDiskFlag:                sl.Bool(true),
            HourlyBillingFlag:            sl.Bool(true),
            PrivateNetworkOnlyFlag:       sl.Bool(true), //Private network flag.
            PrimaryBackendNetworkComponent: &datatypes.Virtual_Guest_Network_Component{
                NetworkVlan: &datatypes.Network_Vlan{Id: sl.Int(1299491)}, 
                MaxSpeed: sl.Int(1000),
            },
        }

        vGuest, err := guestService.Mask("id;domain").CreateObject(&vGuestTemplate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the position of the MaxSpeed attribute. The MaxSpeed is a different attribute than the PrimaryBackenNetworkComponent, 
it must be inside of the networkComponents attribute.

To create a new VM you have to use this rest api example:

```
/*
Create a new Virtual Guest with Vlans and MaxSpeed

createObject() enables the creation of computing instances on an account. This method is a simplified alternative to
interacting with the ordering system directly.
In order to create a computing instance, a template object must be sent in with a few required values.
When this method returns an order will have been placed for a computing instance of the specified configuration.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject/
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/generateOrderTemplate/
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
*/

package main

import (
       "fmt"
       "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/datatypes"
       "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/services"
       "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/session"
       "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/sl"
       "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
       // SoftLayer API username and key
       username    := "set me"
       apikey      := "set me"

       // Create a Virtual_Guest instance as a template
       vGuestTemplate := datatypes.Virtual_Guest{
              Hostname:                     sl.String("sample"),
              Domain:                       sl.String("example.com"),
              MaxMemory:                    sl.Int(2),
              StartCpus:                    sl.Int(1),
              Datacenter:                   &datatypes.Location{Name: sl.String("dal05")},
              OperatingSystemReferenceCode: sl.String("UBUNTU_LATEST"),
              LocalDiskFlag:                sl.Bool(true),
              HourlyBillingFlag:            sl.Bool(true),
              PrivateNetworkOnlyFlag:       sl.Bool(true),
              NetworkComponents: []datatypes.Virtual_Guest_Network_Component{
                     { MaxSpeed: sl.Int( 1000) },
              },
              PrimaryBackendNetworkComponent : &datatypes.Virtual_Guest_Network_Component{
                     NetworkVlan: &datatypes.Network_Vlan{
                           Id: sl.Int(971077),
                     },
              },
       }

       // Create a session
       sess := session.New(username, apikey)

       // Get SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest service
       service := services.GetVirtualGuestService(sess)

       // Use generateOrderTemplate() method to check for errors. Replace this with createObject() when
       // you are ready to order.
       receipt, err := service.GenerateOrderTemplate(&vGuestTemplate)
       if err != nil {
              fmt.Printf("\n Unable to create a virtual server:\n - %s\n", err)
              return
       }

       // Following helps to get the result in json format.
       // Following helps to print the result in json format.
       jsonFormat, jsonErr := json.MarshalIndent(receipt, "", "    ")
       if jsonErr != nil {
              fmt.Println(jsonErr)
              return
       }

       fmt.Println(string(jsonFormat))
}
```

Use generateOrderTemplate() method to check for errors. Replace this with createObject() when you are ready to create the VM.